# Brick SMPS power supply issues

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm working on a system comprised of two boards (power board, screen board) powered either via European outlet (220v 50Hz) or a LiPo battery.

Power handover is achieved via an [autoswitching MUX](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2115.pdf) that defaults to the battery when no voltage is coming from the brick PSU.

Fun begins when I plug the AC side, huge overshoot (~2V), and ringing on the main power rail (not regulated, the one that feeds the LDOs) until the PSU stabilizes, that's causing all sorts of un-funny stuff like "pressing buttons" and resetting the microcontroller (ringing gets through the LDOs).

The PSU is a Meanwell [IRM-10-5](https://www.mouser.es/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/IRM-10-5?qs=WkdRfq4wf1Mbq1AdfDJBoQ==), and even tough it has input filtering the AC side looks like this (fuse is is the mains socket):

AC L - MOV - Xcap - CM choke - PSU

AC N - MOV - Xcap - CM choke - PSU

At the output of the PSU there are a couple hundred mics of LOW ESL tantalum capacitors and from there straight to the power MUX IC and from there to the screen board (350mm unshielded cable).

I've hand soldered a standalone PSU and I can appreciate the same behaviour. The PSU has massive internal capacitance, fast plug/unplug cycles exhibit a very similar response.

My questions:

a) Am I a looser for not testing beforehand the PSU and making sure it had a soft start function and now i'm basically screwed?

b) Have I forgotten something either on the input or the output of the PSU that's upsetting her?

c) Has anyone any tips on how to approach the subject?

Comment: Given that you're using battery backup, could you have the microcontroller manually switch the mux when transitioning from battery to mains? You could have it wait for a few seconds for the PSU to stabilize before switching.

Comment: @C_Elegans, that could be an option, however, it does not explain why a PSU that's supposed to give a regulated output is overshooting by that much on power-up...

Comment: How does the PSU behave at switch-on with just a resistor at its output?

Comment: Show oscillogram of measured overshoot. Show measurement setup.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, winny, I'm off for today, tomorrow I'll post more detailed info and captures/pics!